# Android HelloTabWidget issue

Tags: android

I am attempting to run the HelloTabWidget example from here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

I am able to build, but once it runs it force closes. I ran the debugger in Eclipse and it looks like the error I am getting is in the res/drawable/ic_tab_artists.xml file.

The error I am getting is:
*"org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable"*

This is the xml I have for it, pretty straightforward:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--  When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_artists_grey" android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_artists_white" />
</selector>
```

I'm just confused because the drawable attribute is there...any ideas? The code/XML I have in my implementation is verbatim what they have in the examples, but it just won't run in the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<selector xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

You are missing a colon after http. Perhaps that is the source of the error?

Comment: YES!! Thanks to both of you! I knew it had to be something goofy like that

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just confused because the drawable attribute is there...any ideas

The only thing I came come up with on why you would get that error is that there's a typo in `xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` or a typo in `android:drawable`, but I don't see a typo in either.

- If there were a typo in the `xmlns:android=` decl,   then the `android:drawable` attribute in `item` wouldn't be the right `drawable` attribute, so the run-time would say it isn't there.
- If there were a typo in `android:drawable`, then the run-time error is right: there literally is no `drawable` attribute in `item`.

Comment: Yeah I have scoured this thing for typos hoping to find one, no luck so far though..